# Adding a new Dashboard in OpenStack Horizon

Tags: openstack-horizon

I am trying to create a new dashboard but whenever I do so, I get no changes in the OpenStack dashboard, and the dashboard doesn't get added to it.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as_
import horizon

class BasePanelGroup(horizon.Dashboard):
    name = _("Overview")
    slug = "overview"
    panels = ("hypervisors",)

class Chargeback(horizon.Dashboard):
    name = _("Chargeback")
    slug = "chargeback"
    panels = ('BasePanelGroup',)
    default_panel = 'hypervisor'
    permissions = ('openstack.roles.admin',)

horizon.register(chargeback)
```

From [this link](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/topics/tutorial.html) I have even tried to add the file `_50_chargeback.py` with the given details in it and now my existing OpenStack dashboard doesn't show up.

Comment: Is this a custom dashboard you are making? Can you include urls.py, _50_chargeback.py and some info about the file structure of this dashboard? What URL do you expect this dashboard to appear?

Comment: Maybe also panel.py..

Answer (score 1):

Try to see the error log file generated by the apache server. Also add the panel group configuration file in your enabled local settings. I hope this will help you !

Comment: Thanks Sanskar you were of a great help, i got the answer to my question